# Perl / LWP Trouble to submit a javascript form

Tags: javascript, forms, perl, lwp

I'm trying to make an robot with perl (LWP librairy) to automatize some annoying task.

I'm able to passing through the first login page, but i'm redirected to a second one with a formulaire write in Javascript :

```
<script language='javascript'>
var f;
f=(document.forms.length>0 ? document.forms.item(0) : null);
if (!f) {
    document.writeln("<form method='post' action='' target=''>");
    document.writeln("</form>");
    f=document.forms.item(0);
    }
f.action='URL';
f.target='_top';
f.submit();
</script>
```

Due to this method, my ( HTML::Form->parse( $resultat->content, $resultat->base ) )[0], doesn't find the form & crash.

I really need help on this,

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally this problem was solved by POSTing to the form the js was supposed to create, which of course would break on any change of the dynamically created form.

However, meanwhile there exists

WWW::Scripter http://search.cpan.org/~lxp/WWW-Scripter-0.030/lib/WWW/Scripter.pod and

WWW:Scripter::Plugin::Javascript http://search.cpan.org/~sprout/WWW-Scripter-Plugin-JavaScript-0.008a/lib/WWW/Scripter/Plugin/JavaScript.pm

I haven't tried those though.

Take a look at this discussion too:
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=983385